# Unhandled exception at the end of thread

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, opencv

Hello right now i'm trying to use a thread to read some info about 2 images using OpenCV 2.3.1, while I can retrieve the sizes of the 2 images without a problem, an error occurs when I reach the end of the thread.

> Unhandled exception at 0x00348A56 in OpenCvDemo.exe: An invalid parameter was passed to a function that considers invalid parameters fatal.

Since I can read the size of the images just fine I know they aren't empty or anything. In another test I detached the thread and put it to Sleep for 5 seconds, the main function executed fine and displayed the image, but once the thread woke up and reached the end it crashed the application and displayed the same error as above.

Sadly I need to use OpenCV 2.3.1 since this is just a test for a bigger application.

How can I solve this problem, or at least what is the cause of it?

```cpp
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

void Loop(cv::Mat &image1, cv::Mat &image2) {

    std::vector<uchar> buff1;
    std::vector<uchar> buff2;

    cv::imencode(".png", image1, buff1);
    cv::imencode(".png", image2, buff2);

    int imageSize1 = buff1.size();
    int imageSize2 = buff2.size();

    std::cout << "Size " << imageSize1 << "\n";
    std::cout << "Size " << imageSize2 << "\n";
}

int main()
{
    cv::Mat image1 = cv::imread("C:\\Users\\Cesar\\Pictures\\happyface.png", 1);
    cv::Mat image2 = cv::imread("C:\\Users\\Cesar\\Pictures\\happyface.png", 1);

    std::thread mythread(Loop, std::ref(image1), std::ref(image2));
    mythread.join();

    cv::imshow("name", image1);
    cv::waitKey(0);

    return 0;
}
```

The callstack

```
OpenCvDemo.exe!_invoke_watson(const wchar_t * expression, const wchar_t * function_name, const wchar_t * file_name, unsigned int line_number, unsigned int reserved) Line 224   C++
OpenCvDemo.exe!_invalid_parameter(const wchar_t * expression, const wchar_t * function_name, const wchar_t * file_name, unsigned int line_number, unsigned int reserved) Line 113   C++
[External Code] 
OpenCvDemo.exe!Loop(cv::Mat & image1, cv::Mat & image2) Line 23 C++
[External Code] 
OpenCvDemo.exe!invoke_thread_procedure(unsigned int(__stdcall*)(void *) procedure, void * const context) Line 92    C++
OpenCvDemo.exe!thread_start<unsigned int (__stdcall*)(void *)>(void * const parameter) Line 115 C++
[External Code] 
[Frames below may be incorrect and/or missing, no symbols loaded for kernel32.dll]
```

Comment: It looks like execution is entering `_invalid_parameter` which leads me to believe you are passing an invalid parameter to a library function. Maybe start by looking at the documentation of `cv::imshow`, `cv::imread` and `cv::imencode` to be sure you are using them correctly.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux will do

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux after reading the documentation and testing some code changes, it's look like the imencode function works correctly in the main thread, but for some reason it won't work inside my thread. Testing others functions like imwrite in the thread works just fine.

Comment: It's exceedingly suspicious that `Loop` calls a function as it ends. There are no local objects in it's function whose destruction should cause that. The only thing I can think of is openCV is using a `thread_local` object that is not visible here, or there is Undefined Behavior somewhere consistently corrupting your thread object in a very peculiar way. Try passing your `cv::Mat` objects by copy instead to see if it holds on to them. If that works, I would suspect it's a bug with `cv::imencode`. Edit : Since you `join()` before doing anything else, I don't see what it could be.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I replaced cv::imencode for cvEncodeImage and everything works now. Like you said I think there's a bug in OpenCv 2.3.1 when you try to use imencode inside a thread. thanks for everything.